# When I move objects to a different collection their keyframes dissappear in the dopesheet, how do i get them back?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, collections

I have several collections and noticed that whenever I move an object (that I have already rigged and animated) from one collection to another, the keyframes dissappear from the dope sheet and the time line. The animations i made are still there but the keyframes are gone. Also my summary is empty. I've searched the internet and haven't found anything, neither scrolling up nor 'show hidden' helped. Does anyone know how to get my keyframes back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the collection is disabled (The checkbox column checkbox is deselected) then the keyframes won't show up in the editor, even with show hidden selected.

Comment: @MartyFouts the collections in which the items are are selected in this screenshot; also if i select all collections i still can't see the keyframes

Comment: Can you share a simplified Blend file that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Did you try right click on the collection name and choose "select objects"? Sometimes it refreshes the UI.

Comment: i uploaded the file to the question @MartyFouts :)
@ josh sanfelici i did and it didnt help :') thank you two already for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  Sorry it too so long.  You have filters enable.  Select the filter drop down in the dope sheet and you will see this:

[image: fitler dropdown]

I've highlighted *Collection*  in red.  The filter is preventing you from seeing any animation data *except* for object in *Collection* collection.  Click the 'x' and you'll be able to see everything.

Comment: Ahh it was so easy, thank you so much!! made my day

Comment: Glad I could help.  Wish I'd thought of it sooner.